# What web-based DB2 administration tools are available?

Tags: phpmyadmin, db2, database-administration, db2-luw

I am looking for a web-based GUI to interact with and administer DB2. Something roughly equivalent to phpMyAdmin but for DB2. (I did find and install https://www.php.net/ibm_db2 but that is just a library of PHP functions and not a web-based GUI.)

Comment: I'm looking for this same thing. I'm interested in either open source or IBM products, if anyone knows of any. @Agks, did you find something that works?

Comment: nope, nothing that was web-based.  there are non-web based rich client GUIs that come free from IBM, one is Eclipse-based Data Studio, and the other is called something like "first steps".  i could not use them because there was some kind of platform specific problem: amd x86-64-bit platform. hope you can find something web-based.

Comment: thanks for the response. I did find one, but not one that I can use. I just added it as an answer. hope it will solve your needs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that you'll find is [Technology Explorer for IBM DB2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/db2mc/).

Comment: almost worked but didn't work, but a very good pointer. thank you.

Comment: This tool is very powerful, however, it works better with the most recent DB2 versions. For the installation, you have to follow the Wiki http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/db2mc/index.php?title=Setup

Comment: @Angoca, does this tool allow you to perform CRUD actions on the data?

Comment: I am pretty sure it could execute CRUD actions, because the "ad hoc SQL" option allows to execute all that things. However, the live demo is configured to now change the database. At the same time, I would like to say that the initial question was for administration, not for data manipulation. The TE is designed to view the databases from a DBA perspective, not for object manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I found an open source tool that I'm currently trying to get to work, DBJMIN.
It seems fairly undeveloped, but might work: http://code.google.com/p/dbjmin/

I also found a list of DB Tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools

Some of these aren't phpMyAdmin-like at all, but here are the desktop clients in that list that seem to have similar CRUD capabilities for DB2 and are open source:

- Data Visualization
- DBeauty(JDBC)
- DBEdit
- DBMan
- Jailer (JDBC)
- Orbada(JDBC)
- SQuirreL SQL
- Toad Data Modeler

Also, one of the SQL Maestro tools seems free for non commercial usage.
http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/db2/maestro/

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)  (ps: did the Technology Explorer work for you?  there's a comment on the answer yesterday and activity seems to be picking up on its website -- 105 downloads this week so it might have started working!)

Comment: No problem! :) the technology explorer doesn't seem to give you edit capability. I checked out the example on the website: http://db2mc.dfw.ibm.com/ click the "Log on to live demo" to view it.

Answer (score 1):

Try following one, configuretion is little difficult but after that working fine.

http://www.phpdb2admin.com